# Android recreating ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

How can I recreate listView?
I have listView with items containing few TextViews and I want, to reaload ListView and hide part of those TextViews from every row. I tried setting new adapter, clearing adapter (it makes listView empty), invalidating listView, using notifyDataSetChanged(). Nothing forced ListView to recreate items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) backed by an ArrayList. To change the data, just update the data in the list and call [adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) - Robby Pond

Also please check [Google I/O 2010 - The world of ListView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&t=17m38s)

Comment: I used notifyDataSetChanged() without any effect

Comment: It looks like I have to use notifyDataSetChanged() without any other methods.. Problem solved! :-)